# About two variable real positive function

Tags: calculus, functions, inequality

I had a  similar question about 6 months ago, but unfortunately I had a mistake in my function. Now I want to correct that mistake.

Suppose

$$R(x,y)=(e^{xy}-1)+\frac{(\pi-2)(x-\pi)}{2 \pi}e^{xy}.$$
With some calculating, I guess that, there exists 
 $0.4<\beta<0.5$  such that
$$A)\quad R(x,y)\geq 0,\quad (x,y) \in [\beta,\pi)\times [0, \infty)$$
$$B)\quad R(x,y)\geq 0,\quad (x,y) \in [0,\pi]\times [\frac{1}{\pi}, \infty)$$
Our main purpose is finding the proof of A and B and the exact value of  $\beta$.

I appreciate any solutions, comments and hints.

Comment: "$[\beta,\pi)\times [0, \infty)$". Did you mean "$[\beta,\pi)\cup [0, \infty)$"?

Comment: @MicahWindsor there are two variables, so this is correct.

Comment: @MicahWindsor It should be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, I believe.

Comment: Just making sure, I'm no expert. Didn't know you could multiply intervals until 5 seconds ago when I looked it up lol.

Answer (score 1):

$R(x,y)=\bigg(1+\frac 1{2\pi}(\pi-2)(x-\pi)\bigg)e^{xy}-1=f(x)e^{xy}-1$

We want $R(x,y)=k$ with $k\ge 0$ thus $f(x)e^{xy}=k+1$

Let's take the logarithm:

$xy+\ln(f(x))=\ln(1+k)\ge 0$

First let's examine the case $x=0$: $\quad R(0,y)=(1-\frac 12(\pi-2))e^0-1=1-\frac{\pi}2<0$

So we can now assume $x\neq 0$ and we get the condition for $y$: $\begin{cases} x<0 & y\le -\frac {\ln(f(x))}{x}\\x>0 & y\ge -\frac {\ln(f(x))}{x}\end{cases}$

This is defined for $f(x)>0\iff x>\dfrac{\pi(\pi-4)}{\pi-2}\approx -2.36..$.

If you are interested in the domain where $y\ge 0$ then we need $x>0$ and $f(x)\ge 1\iff x\ge \pi$

(no need to study for $x<0$ as $y$ need always be negative there).

**Note 1:**

In your answer you took $x\le\pi$ but this is not correct.

For having $R(x,y)\ge 0$ for all $y\ge 0$ disregarding the value of $x$, you need $y\ge y_0$

for every $y_0$ solution of $y_0=-\frac{\ln(f(x_0))}{x_0}$, this means $y_0$ need to be always negative, thus $f(x)\ge 1$.

**Note 2:**

I don't see anything particular for your $\beta$, either you've made a mistake, or I didn't understand what you were trying to do.

Comment: Thank you so much @zwin